# Gulp Plugin Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, gulp

I'm concatenating my plugins using Gulp, but they seem to get minified in the wrong order, causing my application to break. I'm using the gulp-order plugin, which I believe I'm using correctly. For testing, I've disabled uglify(). However, the resulting file always starts with Angular, instead of jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
...
//Gulp-order to make sure we load things correctly
var order = require('gulp-order');
...
var pluginOrder = [
  'src/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'src/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
  'src/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'src/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'src/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'src/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'src/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
  'src/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
  'src/bower_components/**/*.js',
  '!src/bower_components/**/*.min.js'
];  //make sure everything loads in the right order

gulp.task('squish-jquery', function() {
  return gulp.src( 'src/bower_components/**/*.js' )
    .pipe(ignore.exclude([ "**/*.map" ]))
    .pipe(order( pluginOrder )).on('error', gutil.log)
    //.pipe(plugins.uglify().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('jquery.plugins.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build')).on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

Beginning of the concatenated file, jquery.plugins.min.js:

```
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.3.15
 * (c) 2010-2014 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
(function(window, angular, undefined) {'use strict';

/* jshint maxlen: false */

/**
 * @ngdoc module
 * @name ngAnimate
 * @description
 *
 * The `ngAnimate` module provides support for JavaScript, CSS3 transition and CSS3 keyframe animation hooks within existing core and custom directives.
 *
 * <div doc-module-components="ngAnimate"></div>
 *
 * # Usage
 *
 * To see animations in action, all that is required is to define the appropriate CSS classes
 * or to register a JavaScript animation via the `myModule.animation()` function. The directives that support animation automatically are:
 * `ngRepeat`, `ngInclude`, `ngIf`, `ngSwitch`, `ngShow`, `ngHide`, `ngView` and `ngClass`. Custom directives can take advantage of animation
 * by using the `$animate` service.
 *
 * Below is a more detailed breakdown of the supported animation events provided by pre-existing ng directives:
 *
 * |
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used gulp-order, but I simply order it in the concatenation like this:

```
gulp.task('js', function(done) {
 return gulp.src([
  './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  './bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
  './bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
  './bower_components/angular-collection/angular-collection.js',
  './assets/js/shopApp.js',
  './assets/js/**/*.js'
 ])
     .pipe(concat('all.js'))
  //.pipe(uglify())
  //.pipe(sourcemaps.write())
     .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
     .pipe(notify('js updated!!'));
});
```

Comment: I did this originally, but I had the same issue, which led to me getting the plugin.

Comment: well sorry then, tried to check the diffs, but nothing found.... only plugins.concat that you use